# Select last n record within group by year month

Tags: mysql, group-by, record

I have a table where I need to get the last 12 records which is grouped by year() month() ASC. I try to use the query below but the result is not as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        tanggal, 
        date_format(tanggal,'%b-%Y') as bulan, 
        sum(sisa_pokok) as jumlah 
    FROM transaksi_detail 
    GROUP BY date_format(tanggal,'%b-%Y') 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12
) sub 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

the query result is as below

[image]

My expected result is sort by bulan column order by year(), month() as follows

```
Bulan     jumlah
Mar-2018  26600000
Oct-2017  1000000
Sept-2017 4500000
and so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM bulan) as year



SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM tanggal) as year , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tanggal) as month, id  FROM  table_name  group by year order by month
```

you can get year same like you can get month  after that put group by and order i hope it will help you

Comment: this line will give  exactly year (you can use your query)

Comment: I understand "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM bulan) as year" will extract the year from bulan column. But how can i order by year and month like my expected data?

Comment: i am not sure can you try and   let us know what kind of error you getting

Answer (score 0):

This works for my situation

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        tanggal, 
        month(tanggal), 
        year(tanggal),
        date_format(tanggal,'%b-%Y') as bulan, 
        sum(sisa_pokok) as jumlah 
    FROM transaksi_detail 
    GROUP BY date_format(tanggal,'%b-%Y') 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12
) sub 
ORDER BY year(tanggal), month(tanggal) ASC
```